# Creating own hyperledger fabric network Error main -> CRIT 003 Cannot define new channel with no Application section

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, channel, hyperledger

I would like to create my hyperledger fabric network but I face an error when I try to create a channel.

> error on outputChannelCreateTx: Cannot define a new channel with no Application section

My configtx file has of course application section, so I dont know what else can be the reason for.

Answer (score 0):

Application has to be defined or referenced under the channel in the profile and also have an Application section if using *ApplicationDefaults.

```
Profiles:
...
ExampleChannel:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
...
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

Organizations:
```

Comment: I did that, I could not find the bug. 
So simply redid everything and then it worked.´...

Was really weird.