# cannot create transaction block : cannot define a new channel in configtxgen

Tags: yaml, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

this question has been already asked [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48747186/creating-own-hyperledger-fabric-network-error-main-crit-003-cannot-define-new) as the question is 10 month old and as there are newer versions on fabric i'm reposting this question.

for the following YAML FILE

```
Organizations:
  - &Smartforce
    Name: SmartforceMSP
    ID: SmartforceMSP
    MSPDir: /home/falcon/dev-iq-smartforce/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/smartforce.com/msp

  - &BusinessPartner1
    Name: FalconMSP
    ID: FalconMSP
    MSPDir: /home/falcon/dev-iq-smartforce/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/falcon.com/msp

    AnchorPeers:
      - Host: localhost
        Port: 7051

  - &BusinessPartner2
    Name: FrostMSP
    ID: FrostMSP
    MSPDir: /home/falcon/dev-iq-smartforce/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/frost.com/msp
    AnchorPeers:
      - Host: localhost
        Port: 8051


# Configuration for the Orderer
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults  #SampleInsecureSolo

  OrdererType: solo

  Addresses:
    - localhost:7050

  # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
  BatchTimeout: 2s

  # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
  BatchSize:
    MaxMessageCount: 10
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 98 MB
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:

Channel: &ChannelDefaults

Profiles:

  TwoPartnerGenesis:
      Orderer:
          <<: *OrdererDefaults
          Organizations:
              - *Smartforce

      Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - <<: *BusinessPartner1
                - <<: *BusinessPartner2  

      Consortiums:
          TwoPartnerConsortium:
              Organizations:
                  - *BusinessPartner1
                  - *BusinessPartner2
  TwoOrgChannel:
    Consortium: TwoPartnerConsortium 
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
           - <<: *BusinessPartner1
           - <<: *BusinessPartner2
```

the result for following file :

input :

> configtxgen -outputCreateChannelTx ./TwoOrgChannel.tx -profile
>   TwoPartnerGenesis -channelID channel01

output :

```
configtxgen -outputCreateChannelTx ./TwoOrgChannel.tx -profile TwoPartnerGenesis -channelID channel01
2018-12-20 12:30:29.818 IST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2018-12-20 12:30:29.824 IST [common/tools/configtxgen] doOutputChannelCreateTx -> INFO 002 Generating new channel configtx
2018-12-20 12:30:29.824 IST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> CRIT 003 Error on outputChannelCreateTx: config update generation failure: cannot define a new channel with no Consortium value
```

please anyone help me to identify the error.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
configtxgen -outputCreateChannelTx ./TwoOrgChannel.tx -profile TwoOrgChannel -channelID channel01
```

I think you selected the wrong profile to create the channel transaction